# Vertically center text and image in one line

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

I need to place an icon and text behind each other on one line. The icon is higher than a single text line, and would like to have the icon and text center aligned. How do I do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The only way I found to do this robustly (well, Scott showed me this...) is to put the figure in a math matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
hello here is $
\begin{array}{l}
\includegraphics{icon}
\end{array}
$ my line.
\end{document}
```

resulting in [image]

Comment: indent code by four spaces. It’s easier if you select the relevant text and just press the code formatting button in the toolbar, the one with the `101 010` image, right next to the colourful little picture.

Comment: @Konrad: thanks. now I'd like to put an image of the result in, but it seems that I should host this image somewhere...is there a make-sence place to put it? or what is the correct way?

Comment: That works for me. Thanx!

Comment: See also [How to vertically center two images](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/how-to-vertically-center-two-images) for alternative solutions with `\vcenter` and `\raisebox`.

Comment: Thanks @Staephan, this is a **much** better solution, IMO.

Answer (score 25):

You can use a `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\vcenteredinclude}[1]{\begingroup
\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics{#1}}%
\parbox{\wd0}{\box0}\endgroup}

\begin{document}

I need to place an icon \vcenteredinclude{test.png}
and text behind each other on one line. The icon is
higher than a single text line, and would like to have the icon and text
center aligned. How do I do that?

\end{document}
```

and the outcome is:

[image: example of a vertically centered picture on a text line]

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly and is really easy to use!