# Misalignment of text in other cells when figure is placed in table (bounding box problem)

Tags: tables, subfloats

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/PaperFigures/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
Table 3. Voltage Loop Results
\linebreak
\begin{tabular}{| p{3cm} | p{2cm} | p{3cm} | l |} 
\hline
Loop Equation & Experimental Value & Loop Description & Loop Figure \\ \hline
$-V_{E}+ V_{1} - V_{d} - V_{4} = 0$ & & Through battery, down right side of resistor                  
complex. Current Flow: $E \rightarrow R_{1} \rightarrow R_{d} \rightarrow  R_{4}$ &    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{CircuitFigure3} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This is what is rendered:
[image: Messed up TeX]

Here is the .pdf of the image if you want to compile this yourself and check it out:
[image: Title it "CircuitFigure3"]
How can I change my code such that the text in the other columns (I realized just now my headers are in the wrong column but that does not matter) will be aligned with the top \hline after the column headers? Also, how can I make the text I write in the cells not stagger so that it fits the "best possible", which ends up looking ugly... I don't want to automatically space out like that.

I need to finish this lab report tonight, so if anyone can help it is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT: The problem has been solved!

Comment: Pl. check whether your figure has empty white space at the bottom.

Comment: It does not, I have made these in adobe illustrator and I do "fit to artwork bounds" so that they are snug to the pixel up to the figure.

Comment: If it is an `.eps` figure, Harish might be right. The important box is the so-called `bounding box`. Include it in your document somewhere else and see if the caption is further below than the lowest point of the figure. And please complete your code snippet to a copy-paste'ble and compilable code such that people can see if there is other issues related to loaded packages etc.

Comment: It is a .pdf figure, i will make it a compilable code.

Comment: @percusse: I have added a compilable code, any ideas now?

Comment: Put your image inclusion code into `\raisebox{-4cm}{ .... }` and see if it is working for you. Also check out the [solutions given for this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/how-to-vertically-center-two-images-next-to-each-other). Also you can change the first two `p{3cm}` to simply `c` for auto sizing.

Comment: @percusse:I have a table without about 5 figures and I ended up needing to go back and forth to adjust to -2.7cm, -3.3cm, etc. but the raisebox trick worked. Could you put that as an answer so that I can accept it. I have solved the problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As OP confirmed this is a baseline positioning problem and can be solved with a hackish solution:

```
\raisebox{-4cm}{  \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{CircuitFigure3} }
```

Alternatively, one control the positioning more precisely as given [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/how-to-vertically-center-two-images-next-to-each-other)

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I could not have figured this out without your help!

Comment: @SamuelReid No problem at all. :)