# Horizontal Filling with LaTeX Tabular

Tags: tables

So, this is a case of "It's LaTeX, surely there's a better way of doing this."

I've tried using `tabular*`, `tabularx`, and a few other things, but I don't quite get what I'm doing wrong with any of them. My current (working) code looks like

```
\usepackage{array}
...
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\flushright\arraybackslash}m{.75\columnwidth}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\flushleft\arraybackslash}m{.25\columnwidth}}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{R|L}
    lots of cool text that is long and needs wrapping
  &
    a very small fixed-width object,
    in my case a graphic made with the igo package
\end{tabular*}
```

My trouble is with my column definitions. I had to choose the `columnwidth`s by hand. I just want the whole `tabular` to span the current `columnwidth`, with one column as shrunk as possible (the second) and the other as wide as possible. This made me think of using `tabular*`, but the [examples](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabular.2A_environment_-_controlling_table_width) I found with `\fill` did not work with line wrapping.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want `tabularx` package and

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedleft}X|l}
  lots of text & \includegraphics{...}
\end{tabularx}
```

Or as pointed out in the comments, you were using vertical centred column so

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedleft}m{#1}}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|l}
  lots of text & \includegraphics{...}
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Or if you want the X column to be like an `m` column, add `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedleft}m{#1}}`

Comment: This is definitely fixing bits of what I was doing wrong with tabularx! Thanks! I'm still working out some silly behaviors, but I think it's stuff I can figure out with how graphics work.

Comment: Awesome! I managed to find [another thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/how-to-vertically-center-two-images-next-to-each-other) solving the graphics issues with \vcenter, and now it all works very prettily!