# How to reduce font size in tikz nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

This my tex code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.5]
\tikzset{input/.style={}} 
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle,draw}}
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thick,black}]

\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [block, right=0.5cm of input,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] (a) {};
\node [block, right of=a,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=2cm,node distance=1.5 cm] (b) {};




\begin{scope}[->,>=latex]

\draw[->] (input) node[above]{\footnotesize{$Msg$}} -- (a);

\foreach \i [count=\xi from 0] in {2,...,-2}{%
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.4 cm]a.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.west) node[right]{\footnotesize{$x_{\xi}$}} ;}

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{tabular}{|r|r|}
\hline
$n$&$n!$\\
\hline
1&1\\
2&2\\
3&6\\
4&24\\
5&120\\
6&720\\
7&5040\\
8&40320\\
9&362880\\
10&3628800\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

Two doubts:

1. How to reduce the font size for x0,x1,...,x4?
2. How to put the table on the RHS of the figure?

Comment: You can use the option `font=...`

Comment: I have already kept that as \footnotesize. How to reduce it further?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the table to be on the right hand side:

- you need to make it part of the `figure` environment so that it floats with it, and
- **not** leave a blank line between `\end{tikzpicture}` and `\begin{tabular}`, and
- as per Alternumdus' comment use `font=` to change the size of the `x0, x1, ..., x4`.

Furthermore, you can:

- add some separation between the two images via `\hspace{}`.
- center the image and the table using `\raisebox{-0.5\height}{}` as explained in [How to vertically center two images next to each other?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/how-to-vertically-center-two-images-next-to-each-other)
- Use `\centering` to center the image

to obtain:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.5]
\tikzset{input/.style={}} 
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle,draw}}
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thick,black}]

\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [block, right=0.5cm of input,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] (a) {};
\node [block, right of=a,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=2cm,node distance=1.5 cm] (b) {};

\begin{scope}[->,>=latex]
    \draw[->] (input) node[above]{\footnotesize{$Msg$}} -- (a);
    
    \foreach \i [count=\xi from 0] in {2,...,-2}{%
        \draw[->] 
                ([yshift=\i * 0.4 cm]a.east) -- 
                ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.west) 
            node[right, font=\footnotesize]{{$x_{\xi}$}} ;
    }
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|}
    \hline
    $n$&$n!$\\
    \hline
    1&1\\
    2&2\\
    3&6\\
    4&24\\
    5&120\\
    6&720\\
    7&5040\\
    8&40320\\
    9&362880\\
    10&3628800\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have already kept that as \footnotesize. How to reduce it further?

Comment: You can use something like `\scriptsize`, or even `\tiny`.