# how to decrease the size of a node and a label - tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, automata

i trying to draw an automata using tikz package, and i want to decrease the size of node and labels on each edge , im have trying to put the option **[scale=0.5]** but it doesn't work !
I have :

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata,shadows,fit,shapes}


 \begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=2.5cm, on grid, auto,thick,initial text=,scale=0.3]
 \node[state, initial]            (0)                          {0};
 \node[state]                     (1)   [above right =of 0]    {1};
 \node[state]                     (2)   [right =of 0]          {2};
 \node[state,accepting]           (3)   [right =of 2]          {3};



 \path[->]      (0)  edge       node           {a:a / 1.61}   (1)
             (0)  edge       node           {b:b/ 0.22}   (2)
             (2)  edge       [loop below]  node         {b:a/ 0.69}   ()
             (2)  edge       node           {b:a/ 0.69}   (3);

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

this give me a not pretty picture :
[image]

Comment: I think you can refer to [How to reduce font size in tikz nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57823/how-to-reduce-font-size-in-tikz-nodes).

Comment: And the "inner sep" property. \draw[inner sep=x].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata,shadows,fit,shapes}


 \begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=2.5cm, on grid, auto,thick,initial text=,scale=0.3]
 \node[state, initial]            (0)                          {0};
 \node[state]                     (1)   [above right =of 0]    {1};
 \node[state]                     (2)   [right =of 0]          {2};
 \node[state,accepting]           (3)   [right =of 2]          {3};



 \begin{scope}[every node/.style={scale=.5}]
     \path[->]   (0)  edge       node           {a:a / 1.61}   (1)
                 (0)  edge       node           {b:b/ 0.22}   (2)
                 (2)  edge       [loop below]  node         {b:a/ 0.69}   ()
                 (2)  edge       node           {b:a/ 0.69}   (3);  
 \end{scope}


 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank u and how about the size of node ?

Comment: For the nodes, I think the library `automata` fixes some dimensions, you need to add something like `minimum size=4ex` after state or/and initial :  `\node[state,minimum size=4ex]`. Perhaps you can redefine the options `state, etc.`

Comment: \node[state,minimum size=4ex] works !

Answer (score 3):

[en] For my part, when it comes to plot a graph, I prefer to note all distances in ems which allows, by changing locally the size of the font to change the graph size

[fr] pour ma part, lorsqu'il s'agit de tracer un graphe, je préfère noter toutes les distances en em ce qui permet, en changeant localement la taille de la font de modifier la taille du graphe

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata,shadows,fit,shapes}


 \begin{document}


 {\tiny
 \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=5em ,auto,thick,initial text=,]
 \node[state, initial]            (0)                          {0};
 \node[state]                     (1)   [above right =of 0]    {1};
 \node[state]                     (2)   [right =of 0]          {2};
 \node[state,accepting]           (3)   [right =of 2]          {3};



 \path[->]      (0)  edge       node           {a:a / 1.61}   (1)
             (0)  edge       node           {b:b/ 0.22}   (2)
             (2)  edge       [loop below]  node         {b:a/ 0.69}   ()
             (2)  edge       node           {b:a/ 0.69}   (3);

 \end{tikzpicture}
 }

 {\small
 \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=5em ,auto,thick,initial text=,]
 \node[state, initial]            (0)                          {0};
 \node[state]                     (1)   [above right =of 0]    {1};
 \node[state]                     (2)   [right =of 0]          {2};
 \node[state,accepting]           (3)   [right =of 2]          {3};



 \path[->]      (0)  edge       node           {a:a / 1.61}   (1)
             (0)  edge       node           {b:b/ 0.22}   (2)
             (2)  edge       [loop below]  node         {b:a/ 0.69}   ()
             (2)  edge       node           {b:a/ 0.69}   (3);

 \end{tikzpicture}
 }

 {\Large
  \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=5em ,  auto,thick,initial text=,]
 \node[state, initial]            (0)                          {0};
 \node[state]                     (1)   [above right =of 0]    {1};
 \node[state]                     (2)   [right =of 0]          {2};
 \node[state,accepting]           (3)   [right =of 2]          {3};



 \path[->]      (0)  edge       node           {a:a / 1.61}   (1)
             (0)  edge       node           {b:b/ 0.22}   (2)
             (2)  edge       [loop below]  node         {b:a/ 0.69}   ()
             (2)  edge       node           {b:a/ 0.69}   (3);

 \end{tikzpicture}
 }


\end{document}
```

[image]