# Problem with the package exam

Tags: exam

I have a problem with the package "exam". I want to put in the orizontal direction 4 images. And move every circle close to the middle of every image. I have post the picture. Thank you very much.

```
\begin{oneparcheckboxes}
 \begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{font={small,it}, labelfont=bf}
  %\subfloat[][\emph{}] % didascalia sottofigura
  {\choice \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{grafico_9.pdf}} \quad
  \captionsetup{font={small,it}, labelfont=bf}
  %\subfloat[][\emph{}] % didascalia sottofigura
  {\choice\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{grafico_9.pdf}} \quad
 % \subfloat[][\emph{}] % didascalia sottofigura
  {\choice\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{grafico_9.pdf}} \quad
  % \subfloat[][\emph{}] % didascalia sottofigura
  {\choice\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{grafico_9.pdf}} \\
  \end{figure}
 \end{oneparcheckboxes}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please make your example a complete document, so we can compile it directly?  You are likely to get more help here if you do.

Comment: Why do you have a `figure` environment nested inside the `oneparcheckboxes` environment?

Comment: See here:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/how-to-vertically-center-two-images-next-to-each-other

Comment: This is not a problem with the `exam` class.  It's a general problem of how to vertically centre a graphic.  Basically get rid of the `figure` stuff and use `\choice $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{grafico_9.pdf}}}$` for each item

Answer (score 2):

You want something more like this:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{oneparcheckboxes}
\choice $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{yourgraphicfile}}}$
\quad
\choice $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{yourgraphicfile}}}$
\quad
\choice $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{yourgraphicfile}}}$
\quad
\choice $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{yourgraphicfile}}}$
\end{oneparcheckboxes}
\end{document}
```

If you are doing this a lot, then you could hide the details by defining a new command:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\vpic}[1]{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{#1}}}$}
\begin{document}
\begin{oneparcheckboxes}
    \choice \vpic{yourgraphicfile} \quad
    \choice \vpic{yourgraphicfile} \quad
    \choice \vpic{yourgraphicfile} \quad
    \choice \vpic{yourgraphicfile}
\end{oneparcheckboxes}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes! it's perfect! it works very wel! :) thanks a lot!

Comment: Also `\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[...]{...}}`; the difference is negligible. Or `\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\includegraphics[...]{...}\end{tabular}`.

Comment: @egreg sì certo,  and several other options that are discussed in the question I linked.

Comment: It has always surprised me that there is no `[vcenter]` option for the `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: @Thruston There is `valign=m` if you load `adjustbox` with the `export` option