# Place text at a defined vertical position on the side of a figure

Tags: tables, floats, align, text, vertical

I want to insert text in a **defined** (= set with a number, not just "bottom", "center" or "top") vertical position at the side of a figure. I managed to insert text at the side, but I can't figure out how to set the vertical position. Ideally, I would like to add different lines of text on the same side, each one with its position.

Here's what I did:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
text on the left side
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, I can insert text and figure in a tabular, but again I don't know how to set the vertical position of the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}   
text on the left & \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image}
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center two images next to each other?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/how-to-vertically-center-two-images-next-to-each-other)

Comment: I prefer the solution provided by the package `graphbox`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350374/5239

Answer (score 1):

You can use a normal `tabular` for the text on the left of the image and by specifying some distance after each newline `\\ [<some v. distance>]`, you can control the vertical position of the text. Since pictures are normally placed above the baseline, you need to specify the `[t]` option from `adjustbox` package for the top text line to be adjusted with the top line of the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[t]{r}
  text on the left1 \\[.5cm]
  text on the left2 \\[.5cm]
  text on the left3 \\
  text on the left4 \\[.5cm]
  text on the left5 
\end{tabular}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,valign=t]{image}
\end{center} 

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Another option would be using Ti*K*Z like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (p) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image}};
\node [left] at ($(p.north west)!.1!(p.south west)$) {text on the left1};
\node [left] at ($(p.north west)!.3!(p.south west)$) {text on the left2};
\node [left] at ($(p.north west)!.5!(p.south west)$) {text on the left3};
\node [left] at ($(p.north west)!.7!(p.south west)$) {text on the left4};
\node [left] at ($(p.north west)!.9!(p.south west)$) {text on the left5};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

with a similar (or better) output:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Without using TikZ or the `tabular` environment, one can use the `minipage` environment to split the page in two subpages. Then, the position of the text can be set using the classical spacing and positioning commands `vspace`, `hspace`, `centering`, `flushleft`, `flushright`, etc. For your example, one can code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \flushright
    text on the left 1

    text on the left 2

    \vspace{1em}
    text on the left 3
\end{minipage} 
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \flushleft
    \includegraphics[]{image}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

and obtain the following output:

[image]